# Get the count of no. of polygons after intersecting shapefiles

Tags: python-2.7, pyqgis-3

There are 2 shapefiles:
1. A polygon shapefile
2. Grid shapefile(which needed to be run in a loop)

Need to intersect the above 2 shapefiles and to get the count of no. of intersected polygons(which is grid wise).

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: You can't mix and match python-2 and pyqgis-3 (python-3)